# Convert regex string with flags to an actual regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

If I have this string

```js
const string = "/a|b|c/gi" // some regex here
```

How do I convert the string to regex?

The below approach doesn't work because the flags are in the string too.

```js
const regex = new Regex(string);
```

Comment: See this where to put the flags using the RegExp constructor https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `slice` method to extract the pattern and flags from the string. The `pattern` is obtained by taking the substring between the first `/` and the last `/`. The `flags` are obtained by taking the substring after the last `/`.

Then `RegExp` constructor can be used to create a regular expression object using the extracted pattern and flags.

```js
const string = "/a|b|c/gi"; 

const pattern = string.slice(1, string.lastIndexOf('/'));
const flags = string.slice(string.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

const regex = new RegExp(pattern, flags);

console.log(regex);
```

The `console.log(regex)` statement will display the resulting regular expression object.